# How to normalize my tables?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I'm in a situation here. I want to normalize my table:

```
  Exam_Papers
ID    Country_Code    Level
1     UK               1
2     UK               2 
3     UK               3
4     UK               4
5     UK               5
6     UK               6
7     UK               7
8     SA               1
9     SA               2
10    SA               3
11    SA               4
12    SA               5
13    SA               6
14    SA               7
15    IN               1
16    IN               2
```

I understand that I could normalize this by putting Levels in a separate table, but then Country_Code would still contain duplicated data, so how normalized should this table be?

Such normalized that Country_Code and Level have their own table?

Also, in this example how is normalization beneficial because either way, making 2 separate tables would mean the FK's would still be duplicated (for example if UK had the ID of 1, my table would contain 7 1's)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what means each column on your table? If your table contains only these fields, I dont see reason for normalization.

Comment: How exactly are you looking to normalize this?  What would be accomplished by that?  In what way is this *not* normalized?  If you have a table of Levels and a table of Countries, supposedly those tables would have some *key* which this table would reference, right?  How would that key differ from what is already in this table?

Comment: If you had a long description for country_code and a long description for level then i can see you wanting them in separate tables..but if there's no extra data for country_code or level is just a number then what you have right now looks fine.

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel You see, I read that normalization is used to defeat duplicated data, in this case why is it not right to normalize? When would you normalize?

Comment: You normalize when the duplication occurs in 2 fields or more, with those fields repeating the same values for a specific set of data. In your case, Country Code and Level, on the sample you provided, does not repeat. You have UK for Level 1,2,3,4,5... If you have, let's say, Country name for each line, then you would be advised to normalize creating a Country table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make two tables in this case. Because as you mentioned you will still require the entry (may be in their id format). Also, I feel if you do it the other way, your performance would degrade in terms of SQL queries.